# VM in KVM with different network, A can ping B but B can't ping A ? (Bridge KVM network)

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, ping, bridge, route

I have 2 VM in KVM, and 2 network `default` and `new`

1 use `defaut` network:(virbr0)

```
192.168.122.0/24
IP: 192.168.122.152.
fowarding: NAT
```

the other use `new` network:(virbr1)

```
192.168.124.0/24
IP: 192.168.124.182
fowarding: NAT
```

Both have empty `iptables` rule and `ufw` inactive

From both VM I can ping to the host and the internet, also host can ping to VM too.

```
quanlm@quanlm-laptop:/home/quan$ ping 192.168.122.152
PING 192.168.122.152 (192.168.122.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.122.152: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.596 ms


quanlm@quanlm-laptop:/home/quan$ ping 192.168.124.182
PING 192.168.124.182 (192.168.124.182) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.124.182: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.509 ms
```

But in the VM use `defaut` network, I can ping the `new` network

```
root@test:~# ping 192.168.124.1
PING 192.168.124.1 (192.168.124.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.124.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.165 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.124.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.551 ms
```

but not the others VM using `new` network

```
root@test:~# ping 192.168.124.182
PING 192.168.124.182 (192.168.124.182) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
```

But also the VM using `new` network can ping directly the `default` network VM

```
root@test2:~# ping 192.168.122.152
PING 192.168.122.152 (192.168.122.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.122.152: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.30 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.122.152: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.10 ms
```

Trace route on `default` VM

```
root@test:~# traceroute 192.168.124.182
traceroute to 192.168.124.182 (192.168.124.182), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  quanlm-laptop (192.168.122.1)  0.565 ms  0.446 ms  0.440 ms
 2  quanlm-laptop (192.168.122.1)  0.454 ms  0.551 ms  0.441 ms
```

Traceroute in `new` VM

```
root@test2:~# traceroute 192.168.122.152
traceroute to 192.168.122.152 (192.168.122.152), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  quanlm-laptop (192.168.124.1)  0.459 ms  0.455 ms  0.453 ms
 2  test.192.168.124.1 (192.168.122.152)  1.234 ms  1.383 ms  1.782 ms
```

Host route:

```
quanlm@quanlm-laptop:/home/quan$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
172.16.161.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.48.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
192.168.64.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.124.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr1
```

The question is how to make 1st VM `default` can ping to 2nd VM `new`?

Comment: What MAC addresses do you see in these 2 VMs? Are they same?

Comment: No, they were different.

Comment: Whats the network config of your bridge machine